# How to differentiate between (x-absent) DE and constant coefficients DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

x-absent second order differential equation is solved by the substitution ( $y'=u$ and $y''=u\frac{du}{dy}$ ). But this equation:

$$y''+6y'+5y=0$$
can't be solved this way, it can be solved only using the method used in second order DE with constant coefficients.

The question is : How to differentiate between (x-absent) DE and constant coefficients DE ?

Answer (score 1):

> $x$-absent second order differential equation is solved by the substitution $y′=u$ and $y′′=u\frac{du}{dy}$.

Actually, this is false. First of all, if $y'=u$, then $y'' = (y')' = u'$, not what you wrote.

Also, the substitution $y'=u$ is useful if the differential equation is $y$ absent, not $x$ absent.

For example, the equation $y'' = y'x$

can be solved by substituting $u = y'$ and $u' = y''$ to get

$$u' = ux$$

which you can then solve.

Comment: No, you are wrong. This substitution is useful in x-absent case. Try it when solving $y''-2yy'=0$. Also, $y''=\frac{d}{dx}u=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}u$

Comment: @MohamedMostafa But the term $u\frac{du}{dy}$ makes no sense, since $u$ is a function of $x$, not of $y$.

Comment: See the comment again I edited it.

Comment: @MohamedMostafa Oh, but then you are not only making a substitution, you are actually looking for $u=u(y)$. I was wrong then, and you were right. The method you are describing, however, only works for a specific set of differential equations, not for all $x$-absent differential equations.

Comment: Yes, that what I noticed, so I ask how to know what set of DE works for this method and what set is not :).

Comment: @MohamedMostafa I am not sure, but I think it must be such that $x$ is absent and the equation is something like $y'' + y\cdot f(y') = 0$. I don't know if there is a name for this...

Comment: @MohamedMostafa But I am not 100%.

Comment: What you thought is right, because it's the form which $u$ appear in the 2 terms which can be divided by, so the result doesn't include $u$. But I didn't find supporting text for this Idea :)